# Maps Api v3: detect Ctrl+click on a marker

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mouseevent

Is it possible to detect keyboard modifiers (ctrl, alt, shift) during a mouse event on a marker in a Google Maps v3 javascript map? If so, how?

Comment: See this answer / question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757851/handling-ctrlclick-on-google-maps

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it's nothing that's built in to the maps API.

This is back for the 2 API, but will work for three. There's some discussion of order of event problems with FireFox [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/b7b763cbcac87243), so you'll have to test a bit.

Hopefully that helps.