# Handling ctrl+click on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make the user select multiple markers on my map by pressing control key and click on the marker.

For doing this, I write this code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
    // detect if is pressed ctrlKey or not to do stuff
}
```

In the GoogleMaps V3 [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) there is no info or documentation about this `e` object, beyond the `latLng` property.
But when I debug with Google Chrome, I see this `Ra` object that contains exactly what I needed. 
My question is, it is safe to hardcode this undocumented `Ra` access to obtain if ctrlKey is pressed?

[image]

Comment: There's plenty information about the [MouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) in the API docs.  Anything undocumented should not be considered safe to use; future updates to the API could remove or amend those undocumented objects without prior warning

Comment: What exactly is "exactly what I needed"? `Ra` is most of the time undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As asked for in comment, what contains `Ra` that is important? My experience is, that google maps change those internal variable / object names constantly.

---

However, had made a demo to show how to select multiple markers by holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> down and clicking on the markers :

See fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/FbGa5/**
***Notice** : You must activate the iframe by clicking on the map once before <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or any other keypress can be captured.*

Keep track of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key :

```
var selecting = false,
    selectedMarkers = [];

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  selecting = ((e.keyIdentifier == 'Control') || (e.ctrlKey == true));
}
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  selecting = false;
}
```

Select markers if <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-key is down and a marker is clicked. If a marker is selected, it turns blue, if a marker is deselected it turns back to red :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   if (!selecting) return;
   var id = this.id;
   var index = selectedMarkers.indexOf(id);
   if (index>-1) {
     this.setIcon('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png');
     selectedMarkers.splice(index, 1);
   } else {
     selectedMarkers.push(id);             
     this.setIcon('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png');
   }
});
```

Conclusion : You do not need `Ra` or any other argument in the marker click event in order to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for this man! For clarification, I know that probably `Ra` will be a "ghost" object, that's because I asked. For "exactly what I needed", I must say, that inside this object is a flag `ctrlKey` that would help me a lot.

Comment: @AgustinMeriles - You are welcome! Now I see. Tried to monitor Ra on various events, almost always seemed to be undefined.

Comment: @AgustinMeriles, I have made a small update to the code and a new fiddle. The ctrl-key was not detected properly in FireFox, this is corrected now. Also tested with Opera.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the class members are changed due to minification.
My idea, that i know is not perfect, is to look for the MouseEvent by type 
and not by name. Then, when found , give it a constant name that you know

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
    // detect if is pressed ctrlKey or not to do stuff

   //detect the mouse event member by type
    //and always give it the name "mouseEvent"         
    for (var key in e) {
        if (e[key] instanceof MouseEvent) {
           e["mouseEvent"] = e[key];
           break;
         }
     }

   // e.mouseEvent.ctrlKey ....

}
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks !

Comment: It's no longer working no idea why. `shiftKey` always returning false. I think it has something to do with google api.

Comment: Try to use a fixed version of the google api by adding the version number in the google API URL.
Like this :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.29 
        &key=YOUR_API_KEY.

See More Here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

This will tell you if the issue is related to some specific version of the google API or related to your code

Comment: Agreed, this method of looking for the modifier in the MouseEvent is no longer working with the current version, shiftKey, ctrlKey no longer update